# Polynomial Regression - results accuracy between two algorithms

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, regression

I know that I can find a polynomial regression's coefficients doing `(X'X)^-1 * X'y` (where `X'` is the transpose, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#Matrix_form_and_calculation_of_estimates) for details).

This is a way of finding the coefficients; now, there is (as far as I know) at least one other way, which is by minimizing a cost function using gradient descent. The former method seems to be the easiest to implement ( I did it in C++, I have the latter in Matlab ).

What I wanted to know is the advantage of one of these methods over the other.

Upon a particular dataset, with very few points, I found that I couldn't find a satisfactory solution  using `(X'X)^-1 * X'y`, but gradient descent worked fine and I could get an estimation function that made sense.

So what's wrong with the matrix resolution over gradient descent ?  And how would one test a regression results, having all the details hidden from the user ?

Comment: Both approaches should yield identical results.  If not, you either have a (almost) singular matrix X, or made a mistake somewhere.  Maybe you tried too few points?  The number of points must be greater or equal as compared to the number of coefficients you want to determine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: No it doesn't belong to math stackexchange. This is a question about machine learning algorithms. As everyone knows, Machine learning is the science of getting computers to act without being explicitly programmed. Therefore, this is a stackoverflow question.

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't fit on [so], but perhaps [stats.se] would be a better fit (though I'm not 100% sure).

Comment: Question on hold... oh, well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both methods are equivalent. Iterative method is much more computationally efficient thanks to lower storage and the avoidance of matrix inverse calculation. The method outweighs the closed form (matrix equation) methods [especially when `X` is huge and sparse](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23128/solving-for-regression-parameters-in-closed-form-vs-gradient-descent).

Make sure the row number of `X` is larger than the column number of `X` to avoid the underdetermined problem. Also check out the condition number of `X'X` to see if the problem is ill-posedness. If that is the case, you may add a small regularization factor in the closed form (`(X'X + lambda * I)^(-1) * X'y`) where `lambda` is a small value and `I` is the identity matrix.

Comment: The length of y is by definition equal to the number of rows in X. I think you meant that the number of features in X (e.g. the number of columns) should be less than the number of rows.

Comment: yes, I corrected. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I wonder if it is mathematically proven that both algorithms should yield the same result. I guess it's not, because gradient descent may converge to a local minimum...

Comment: @CTZStef Thank you CTZStef. You are absolutely right that gradient descent may converge to local minima. This is due to the characters of your cost function. I'm not sure whether I'm correct, but when dealing with polynomial regression in your case, I guess you still convert it to a linear problem Xw=b where X=[1 x x^2,...] are known matrix with your training data, and you are going to solve w. So the cost function |Xw-b|^2 is convex, and there is only one (global minimum).

Comment: @CTZStef I nominated for the reopen on your question, now there are 3 votes.